# C++ typedef enum and just enum

Tags: c++, typedef

What exactly is the difference between:

```
typedef enum {
  something1,
  something2,
  .....
  somethingN
} myEnum;
```

end just

```
enum myEnum{
  something1,
  something2,
  .....
  somethingN
};
```

I know in first case I have typedefed unnamed enum, of course, just wonder which approach is better and why?

Comment: With C++11 now, you should use neither: `enum class` is safer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout While certainly an improvement, `enum class` is far from a complete replacement. It gives you two things (mandatory scoping, and no implicit conversions) but sometimes you want only one.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: This doesn't answer the original question. It only redirects it somewhere else.

Answer (score 19):

The first variant was useful in C, because otherwise you would have to write `enum myEnum` everywhere you wished to use it.

This is not the case in C++.  So, AFAIK, there is no benefit to the first case in C++ (unless you're defining e.g. an interface that needs to be shared with C).

Answer (score 16):

No difference. In fact, the first version is C-style coding.

C++11 has introduced [stronly-typed enum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations), which you define as:

```
enum class myEnum  //note the 'class' keyword after the 'enum' keyword
{   
  something1,
  something2,
  .....
  somethingN
};
```

In C++03, enums are not type-safe, they're essentially integers, and can mix with other integral types implicitly, and another problem with them is that they don't have scope; you can use its member without qualifying its type; you can use `something1`. Whereas C++11 strongly-typed enums are type-safe, and they've scope; you've to use `myEnum::something1`.

Comment: It's not quite as bad as you suggest in C++03.  Enums do define a distinct type, you can overload on them, and you can define overloaded operators using them.  The implicit conversion to an integral type is a bit of a bother, but I've not found it to be a problem in practice.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Alright, I added the major problem with C++03 enums. Also, if they were not bad, then C++11 would not have added strongly-typed enums.

Comment: Scope was never a problem. `namespace scope_for_my_enum { enum { foo, bar }; }`, or `class scope_for_my_enum { enum { foo, bar }; };` depending on whether you want to allow clients to dispense with it. In fact, this means old enums *are more flexible* in terms of scoping.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That is a workaround which tacitly admits the scoping-problem with C++03 enums, which is exactly why you came up with a workaround. Also, if you use such scoping workaround, the readability decreases a lot.

Comment: @Nawaz It proves it's not a *major* problem. It's just a nuissance. There is a simple workaround that even gives you more flexibility. The big problem with old enums is the implicit conversions *because there's no workaround for them*.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Your earlier comment was not on "major". Anyway, I edited it.

Comment: I think that the main motivation is that people wanted the enum constants to be scoped (in some cases---not always).  Beyond that, there is a general trend to less implicit conversions (although the horse is already out of the barn there).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the first one. It is *almost* the same as the other one. In C++11, with the second you can write `myEnum::something1` but not with the first one. Also in C++11, you can forward declare enums in some cases, but it is impossible to do forward declarations of unamed types and you can't forward declare typedefs either.